# Variadic Generation of Tuples

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to write a c++ code that based on an integer value and a coordination, generates a set of tuples and function calls like this:

```
// dimension = 1, input = (i) generated tuples: (i-1) (i), (i+1)
// dimension = 2, input = (i,j) generated tuples: (i-1, j), (i, j-1), (i, j),(i+1, j), (i, j+1)
<typename Index, int dimension>
void my_function(Index input)
{
    // some magic here that generates the following code or sth like this
    get_value(generated_tuple0);
    get_value(generated_tuple1);
    ....
    ....
    get_value(generated_tupleN);

}
```

I'm not good at template programming, maybe with variadics in C++11 it could be possible.

Comment: What is `Index`? And where are the values for `i` and `j` coming from?

Comment: @AlirezaMajidi , why tuples?You cannot use a vector?

Comment: For dimension n you want  hyper-cube centered on the input...right?

Comment: @Atomic_alarm Unfortunately no, its part of a framework, so I couldn't change it.

Comment: @marom Yes, actually its a class of stencil computation. [stencil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_code)

Comment: What is `Index`? A `std::tuple` of `dimension` `int`s (or `double`s)?

Comment: Note that template parameter `int dimension` seems unneeded as you may use `std::tuple_size` on your tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a compile-time solution. It generates a the required tuples on the fly and calls the passed function with these.

```
template<typename TupleType, typename FunctionType, size_t N, typename = std::enable_if_t<N != std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TupleType> >::value> >  //why SFINAE required?
void tuple_caller_impl(TupleType&& t, FunctionType&& f, std::integral_constant<size_t, N>)
{
    --std::get<N>(t); f(t); ++std::get<N>(t);
    ++std::get<N>(t); f(t); --std::get<N>(t);

    tuple_caller_impl(std::forward<TupleType>(t), std::forward<FunctionType>(f), std::integral_constant<size_t, N+1>());
}

template<typename TupleType, typename FunctionType>
void tuple_caller_impl(TupleType&& t, FunctionType&& f, typename std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TupleType> >::type)
{
    f(std::forward<TupleType>(t)); // finally call function on the unchanged tuple
                                   // could also be done by specializing the 0-th call to tuple_caller_impl
}

template<typename TupleType, typename FunctionType>
void tuple_caller(TupleType&& t, FunctionType&& f)
{
    tuple_caller_impl(std::forward<TupleType>(t), std::forward<FunctionType>(f), std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>());
}
```

Apply it like

```
int main()
{
    auto f = [](auto const& t) { std::cout<<"call function with ("<<std::get<0>(t)<<","<<std::get<1>(t)<<","<<std::get<2>(t)<<")"<<std::endl; };
    auto t= std::make_tuple(1,5,3);

    tuple_caller(t,f);
}
```

The previous prints the following to screen:

```
call function with (0,5,3)
call function with (2,5,3)
call function with (1,4,3)
call function with (1,6,3)
call function with (1,5,2)
call function with (1,5,4)
call function with (1,5,3)
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/766a270a34079f7d)

Note that the call order differs from that in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Index is a tuple this is a possible solution:

```
template <class Index, int I, int dimension>
struct tuple_builder_t
{
    static void build(std::vector<Index> &result, Index center)
    {
        Index iter = center;
        for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
        {
            std::get<I - 1>(iter) = std::get<I - 1>(center) +i;
            tuple_builder_t<Index, I, dimension>::build(result,  iter);
        }
    }
};

template <class Index, int dimension>
struct tuple_builder_t<Index, dimension, dimension>
{
    static std::vector<Index> build(std::vector<Index> &result, Index center)
    {
        Index iter = center;
        for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
        {
            std::get<dimension - 1>(iter) = std::get<dimension - 1>(center) +i;
            result.push_back(iter);
        }
    }
};

template <class Index, int dimension>
void my_function(Index index)
{
    std::vector<Index> result;
    tuple_builder_t<Index, 1, dimension>::build(result, index);
}
```

It's a neat problem, I already found myself in front of somethng similar (iterate over the dimension of an hypercube)